# double negative value in java

Tags: java, double

I am trying to add -ve to double

```
List<double> values={12.34,-12}
double value =0.00;
for(double b: values)
{

value += b;
}
```

I am expecting value of b =0.34 but it returning me 0.399999999985

any idea why it is returning me the wrong value.

Comment: Actually, it gives `0.33999999999999986`

Comment: Ignoring all the typos in your question and the non-compilable code, that's not wrong. It's just floating-point math.

Comment: Thanks How can I solve this problem?

Comment: float[] values={12.34f,-12};
float value =0.00f;
for(float b: values)
  replace 1st three lines with this. then output comes 0.34000

Comment: try this one: double a=12.34;
        double b=-12;
        System.out.println(String.format("%.2f" , a+b)); output:0.34